# Gfortran compilation error when declaring more than one set of variables

Tags: fortran, mingw, gfortran

I am using gfortran to try to compile a Fortran 95 free form code in Windows 8.1.

```
λ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

Which as can be clearly seen was installed using MinGW installer.

I have used gfortran in linux without any hitch. But due to project requirements I need to use Windows to develop and test. The intention of using fortran is for developing performance intensive sections of scientific simulations.

The error that I am facing is something that I did not observe in linux.

I shall describe the minimum valid code and erroneous code.

**VALID CODE**

I have a file named **test.f95** which contains the following code.

```
program test

IMPLICIT NONE

! First set of variables declaration 
REAL:: A,B,C
A = 1.0
B = 2.0
C = 3.0

WRITE(*,*) A * B
WRITE(*,*) C

! Second set of variables declaration

!REAL:: D
!D = 4.0
!WRITE(*,*) D

end program test
```

As it can be seen that the code above has some of the lines commented out.
I shall come to it later.

Now when I compile it using gfortran it compiles successfully.

```
λ gfortran test.f95
λ ls
a.exe*  test.f95
```

I run the executable and it produces expected results.

```
λ a.exe
  2.00000000
  3.00000000
```

**ERRORNEOUS CODE**

The same file test.f95 contains comments that I mentioned previously are uncommented to produce

```
program test

IMPLICIT NONE

! First set of variables declaration 
REAL:: A,B,C
A = 1.0
B = 2.0
C = 3.0

WRITE(*,*) A * B
WRITE(*,*) C

! Second set of variables declaration

REAL:: D
D = 4.0
WRITE(*,*) D

end program test
```

What we have done is to un-comment 3 lines of code which is used to declare, set and print a real variable D. This is the 2nd set of variable that we are describing in this program.

However, when we TRY to compile we are having compilation failure.

```
λ gfortran test.f95
test.f95:16:8:

REAL:: D
        1
Error: Unexpected data declaration statement at (1)
test.f95:17:1:

 D = 4.0
 1
Error: Symbol 'd' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

So, as can be seen we have an error.

I have not experienced such an error before in linux and since I can not even define a second variable.

**That is, the problem occurs whenever I declare the 2nd set of variables.**

**QUESTIONS**

So, the questions are,

**i) Have I made any mistake in the code ?**

**ii) Why this error occurred ?**

**ii) How do I solve this error ?**

Comment: Welcome, the problem is described in the link. Tall variable declarations must be placed before executable declarations. You solve this by moving the `REAL:: D` declaration at just behind the `REAL:: A,B,C`. I recommend to specifically search for the error message on this site.